# Python (2.7.5.) need assistance with calendar module

Tags: python

This is the sample question I got:

> Create a Python program weekday.py that reads the input from the form. To determine the day of the week, you can use a function from the calendar module. The weekday function can be called like this:
>
> ```
> weekday = calendar.weekday(y, m, d)
> ```
>
> ... assuming you have the year, month, and day in variables `y`, `m`, and `d`. This will put an integer 0 - 6 in the variable `weekday`, where 0 is Monday, 1 is Tuesday, and so on.
>
> Use a series of `if` statements to produce output like this on the generated page (with the appropriate weekday, of course - this is what you'd produce if the `weekday` was 0):
>
> ```
> <p>That's a Monday.</p>
> ```

This is my what is did so far:

Python (newer version):

```
import cgi
import calendar
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

print "Content-type: type/html"
print
y = form['year'].value
m = form['month'].value
d = form['date'].value
weekday = calendar.weekday(y, m, d)
if weekday == 0:
    print "<p> That's monday </p>"
if weekday == 1:
    print "<p> That's tuesday </p>"
if weekday == 2: 
    print "<p> That's wednesday </p>"
if weekday == 3:
    print "<p> That's thursday </p>"
if weekday == 4:
    print "<p> That's friday </p>"
if weekday == 5:
    print "<p> That's saturday </p>"
if weekday == 6:
    print "<p> That's sunday </p>"
```

Can someone please help me?? I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: You are not reading any input from a form here. What fields does the form use that connects to this script?

Comment: Seriously?! You have no idea what you are doing my friend. You haven't defined variables y, m, or d. And then you're checking against d while you should be checkong those if statements against 'weekday' becuase that's what the number 0-6 will be in. Provided you give correct numbers in that function call

Comment: mavili: Yeah...this is messed up.

Comment: @mavili: not to worry, I do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to retrieve the `y`, `m` and `d` values from the `form` object first:

```
y = int(form['year'].value)
m = int(form['month'].value)
d = int(form['day'].value)
```

assuming that the HTML form that submits to this script has `year`, `month` and `day` fields. Looking at `http://www2.cs.sfu.ca/CourseCentral/165/ggbaker/1134-dist/lab/files/lab10-dateform.html`, your original form does use exactly those fields. GET and POST provided data are always strings, but the `calendar.weekday()` function wants you to pass in integer values, so here they are parsed into integers with the `int()` function.

Then, you are assigning the *output* of the `calendar.weekday()` function to the name `weekday`, but are not using that at all in the rest of the code. Perhaps you need to re-examine what all those `if` statements should be testing against.

Comment: And also make sure you're checking for the variable 'weekday' instead of 'd'

Comment: @mavili: I am trying not to solve *all* the problems at once.. hopefully the OP does *some* (more) of the work themselves. I've added a hint.

Comment: Thank you! I'm still trying to figure out by looking at your code

Comment: I just edited the newer version of mine, but I still get an error saying that an integer is required...

Comment: @Fred: Ah, yes, form values are *strings*, so you need to turn them into integers by using `int()`. `int(form['year'].value)`, etc.

Comment: but if I do that, the file automatically saves when I press the Submit button in my html

Comment: What do you mean, *the file automatically saves*? You mean the browser asks you to save the response? Then you need to set the right HTTP response headers in your CGI. Are you setting the correct content type?

Comment: I see from http://www2.cs.sfu.ca/CourseCentral/165/ggbaker/1134-dist/lab/9 that you already should have known about the `int()` function, btw. Did you pay attention? :-)

Comment: @Fred: the form is not the problem. Your Python CGI script is. In lab 8 (http://www2.cs.sfu.ca/CourseCentral/165/ggbaker/1134-dist/lab/8) you already created a CGI script that returned HTML. The first line that that script prints is the `Content-Type` header. That header is *important*, make sure your new script prints it too.

Comment: Just re-read the file again and found out that I misspelled text/html to type/html in my Content-Type

Comment: @Fred: \o/ You found it. :-)

Comment: @Fred: Thank you! I am not a teacher, I am a software developer. I do train co-workers.